# stream work fine for the first time but then stops

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Future<bool> connectServer(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      // await _displayTextInputDialog(context);

      // socket = await Socket.connect(_textFieldController.text, 2508,
      //     timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4));
      socket = await Socket.connect("192.168.14.148", 2508,
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4));
      stream = socket.listen(null);
      return true;
    } on SocketException {
      await Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        '/connectionE',
      );

      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> receiveMessage() {
    final completer = Completer();

    print("before");
    stream.onData((data) {
      print(data);
      if (data.contains(49)) {
        print(data);
        completer.complete(extractData(data));
        stream.cancel();
      }
    });
    print('after');
    return completer.future;
  }

  Future<String> sendAndWait(
      BuildContext context, String message, int code) async {
    try {
      sendMessage(message, code);
      print("sended");
      String reply = await receiveMessage();
      stream.onData((data) {});
      print(reply);
      return "";
    } on SocketException {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
        context,
        '/serverDownE',
      );
    }

    return "2";
  }
```

receiveMessage work on the first time, but then stop working, it doesn't even get into the onData function. Does someone know why is this happening? I cant use cancel on the subscription, cancel and start new one because when I start listening again I get an error Bad state stream has already been listening. I can't close the socket because the the server is a stateful server.

Comment: What do you want to do when you receive 49 from the socket? If you just stop listening, data could still arrive. If feels like you really want to close the socket? If you do, that will break the stream for you with an `onError`

Comment: 49 means start of message. When I get 49 I want to return the message I got. It works good for the first time, but next I will try to do for or listen I will get an error. I want to stop listening but keep the socket alive.

Comment: You can't `return` from listening to a stream. You need to process the data as it arrives in the `(data) { /* do something with data */}` function you supplied. If you are reading messages from a socket, you need to look at `data`, see if that constitutes a complete message and then, most likely, call another function with that complete message. The tricky bit comes when you have a partial message. You have to save that in a local variable and append the next chunk of `data` to see if that's enough for a whole message. Save any extra bytes left over and carry on.

Comment: I ran into a new problem, I received the messages into a q, every message that arrive get in to this q. But now I cant access the q, I tried using while loop until the message get into the q. But no matter what I do the message get into the q only after the function ends.

Comment: You don't show any difference in the code in the question. If it's changed, update the question.

Comment: just change it :)

Comment: This line: `do {} while (replys.isEmpty);` is just going to spin, never letting anything else execute - so never allowing anything to write to the queue. You need to embrace Dart's async capabilities, in particular, things like `Completer` to signal to other async methods that something is complete/available and other methods can await them. There's a deprecated package https://pub.dev/packages/semaphore that provided a nice wrapper around completers and futures that you can borrow ideas from if you like the semaphore model.

Comment: Also check out the `ByteDataReader` from https://pub.dev/packages/buffer which lets you add the output of the socket listener, and then `await` a complete message using `readAhead(int length)`